# Crear subdominios personalizados con PHP para usuarios

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, dominio

Quiero que cuando mis usuarios se registren, se les proporcione un subdominio con su nombre de usuario de forma automática con **PHP**. Lo único que he llegado a averiguar es que debo crear un **record** del tipo **A** en los **DNS** de mi dominio: `*.dominio.com       IN  A       127.0.0.1`

Pero no sé como gestionarlo desde el servidor para que por ejemplo: `antonio.dominio.com`, cargue: `dominio.com/user/antonio`.

Una vez tenga el resultado anterior ya podría hacer la verificación del usuario y demás.

Comment: `dominio.com/user/antonio` no seria un subdomio, es una URL del dominio `dominio.com`. Subdomio sería por ejemplo `antonio.dominio.com`

Comment: Claro, pero lo que intento explicar, es cómo hago para que aunque el usuario vea en su URL antonio.domini.com, realmente el servidor pereciba por ejemplo, dominio.com/user/antonio. Es decir, todo el código está en la web principal y realmente los subdominios no tienen carpeta en el servidor, pero quiero que puedan acceder desde su propio subdominio y que el servidor reconozca al usuario, y esa sería forma más sencilla de hacerlo.

Comment: Revisa este [tutorial](https://likegeeks.com/es/enrutamiento-dinamico-de-subdominios-en-laravel/), es para Laravel, pero no se ve difícil de adaptar a cualquier otro Framework

Comment: que sistema operativo estas utilizando para tu servidor?

Answer (score 5):

pudes hacerlo asi:

ejecutamos el comando:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/servertest.local.conf
```

y dentro agregamos esto:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName servertest.local
    ServerAlias *.servertest.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@servertest.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/servertest.local
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/servertest.local.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/servertest.local.access.log combined
    LogLevel warn

    <Directory "/var/www/html/servertest.local">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

cargamos la configuracion:

```
sudo a2ensite servertest.local.conf
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

configuramos el dns server:

```
*.servertest.local A 127.0.0.1
```

reiniciamos los servicios con:

*nota: puede ser `httpd` en vez de `apache2` para centos o redhat*

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2

o

service apache2 restart
```

agregamos los permisos: para las carpetas

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html/
sudo chown -R <tuusuario> /var/www/html/
```

ahora el archivo index.php

```
<?php

$domain = $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ];

if(count(explode( ".", $domain )) > 2){

    list( $username ) = explode( ".", $domain );
    echo $username;

   // header('Location: http://www.servertest.local/user/'.$username);

}
else{
    echo "bienvenido a la pagina de inicio!";
}
?>
```

ahora ejemplo:

```
solicitud:
http://servertest.local/

resultado:
bienvenido a la pagina de inicio!

solicitud:
http://antonio.servertest.local/

resultado:
antonio
```